# How can I host Ruby and PHP applications on the same server?

Tags: linux, web-server, vps

I have a ruby application that I run on a VPS at DigitalOcean. I also have some PHP applications that I use regularly running on a different VPS at Linode. When I deploy the ruby application and start it on port 80, navigating to my domain (let's call it 745.com) loads the Ruby application and that works without an issue.

I want to restrict this ruby application to a sub-domain (ruby.745.com) so I can serve other HTML/PHP scripts on 745.com - After searching for a bit, I learned that I can create two VPS servers and use DNS to point 745.com to the HTML/PHP VPS and ruby.745.com to the ruby application running on the secondary VPS (within the same provider). While I see this working, it'll cost more to maintain both.

So my question is how can I serve both of these technologies on the same VPS?

Comment: This question already has answers here - search: [Apache reverse proxy](http://serverfault.com/search?q=apache+reverse+proxy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Ruby and PHP applications on the same web server by configuring separate virtual hosts to serve different content. Both Apache and Nginx can be setup that way.

You can even run mixed code on the same virtual host by utilizing proxy rules as mentioned by [Iain](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain).

Comment: That link basically says use a proxy; we have lots of Q&A about that already. Also we prefer answers to have content, not pointers to external content over which we have no control.

Comment: Link was removed.